# Prestashop change references order to the scripts in head tag

Tags: jquery, prestashop-1.6, head

I'm using Prestashop version 1.6.1.17. I installed a module called Super Abandoned Cart and I have the following error in Prestashop back office:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I found out that I should put the references to the jquery scripts first.

I don't know how to do that in Prestashop.

These are the references generated automatically after installing some modules (PrestaQnA and Super Abandoned Cart):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/prestaqna/js/dh42.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/superabandonedcart/views/js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the modules position in backoffice -> modules -> position?

Comment: @sadlyblue the problem is that I have that error in back office

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

In prestashop, to load jQuery file, we use addJquery() function.

In order to load jQuery file before any other file you might want to call this function before loading any other js file.

e.g.

```
public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
{
    if (Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name) {
        $this->context->controller->addJquery();
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/back.js');
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/310898-force-jquery-to-load-as-the-first-js-file-before-any-other-js-files/